# Best practice for handling api key in Play framework

Tags: google-maps, playframework

I am trying to build a website with the **Play framework** that will need to request some directions from the **google maps api**.

For those requests, I need to use my *google api key*. Obviously, I don't want to hardcode this value for multiple reasons. Is there a specific file configuration file that is suited for this usage in the *Play framework*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you don't want to hardcode your key for security reasons - ie. you are checking into a public Github repository, in which case you have a couple of options:

I usually use an environment variable for local development:

`maps.api.key=${?MAPS_API_KEY}`

ie. where `MAPS_API_KEY` is an environment variable configured on your machine.

For production deployment I either:-

1.) Set the value dynamically at build time from a private property file. Usually my approach if using a CI tool for the build.

2.) You could also pass it in as a system variable at startup:

`/path/to/yourapp/bin/yourapp -Dmaps.api.key="YOURKEY"`

You will need to modify your startup script if using `activator dist` to create your distribution.